# Use node exec to access a function in a python file

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

I am new to node's `child_process` and I am trying to execute python and get its results back to node

I want to use exec, not to execute a simple command but to access a python file and execute it

Say my `python.py` is

```
try :
    import anotherPythonFile
    print('hello2')
    # anotherPythonFile.names().getNames()  
except Exception as e :
    print(e)
```

I try to test this and have `hello2` returned ,but I get nothing

```
exec('D:\prjt\test\python.py', (er, stdout, stderr)=>{
  console.log('exec test', stdout);      
})
```

If this worked I would uncomment and execute `anotherPythonFile.names().getNames()`

What is the error here?

Also, can I access the `anotherPythonFile` directly and somehow set the function I want to execute ? I want to do (example)

```
exec('D:\prjt\test\anotherPythonFile.py.names().getNames()', (er, stdout, stderr)=>{
  console.log('exec test', stdout);      
})
```

Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of running a Python script from Node.js and reading its output:

hello.py

```
print("Hello from Python!")
```

main.js

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const py = spawn('python3', ['/home/telmo/hello.py'])

py.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`${data}`)
});
```

Running `node main.js` returns:

```
Hello from Python!
```

#### Alternatives

You can also use `execFile` instead of `spawn`:

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process');

const py = execFile('python3', ['/home/telmo/hello.py'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error || stderr) {
    // Handle error.
  } else {
    console.log(stdout)
  }
})
```

Or `exec`:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const py = exec('python3 /home/telmo/hello.py', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error || stderr) {
    // Handle error.
  } else {
    console.log(stdout)
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi there. Yes, I also know about `spawn`, is very flexible, but I am experimenting with `exec` and I was wondering if I could use `exec` for python files. There is a big python+node project coming up and I want to research all the options first. So `exec` is not a choice for python files, only `spawn` ? Thank you

Comment: @codebot Okay, I wrote two more examples with `execFile` and `exec` to give you some options over `spawn`.

Comment: You might want to turn the `exec` into a promise so you can await for it. Would you like an example of that?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. One last thing, is possible to define input arguments and/or a specific  function in exec ? Something like `exec('python3 /home/telmo/hello.py aPythonFunctionToExecute argumentOne argumentTwo'` Thanks

Comment: I think you'd have to use `execFile` or `spawn` for that. At least that's what it looks like in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).